# Macro to Run When New Row Added to Table Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my macro to run only when my table has a new row added.
On the sheet that has the table, I have included this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'This module verifies row numbers in the database by matching them to the opportunities in the Projects
    'worksheet. It then assigns row numbers in the Projects worksheet.

    Dim Records As Range

    Set Records = Range("Records")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Records, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           Call FindRow       
    End If        
End Sub
```

And this is the `FindRow` code:

```
Sub FindRow()
    'This module verifies row numbers in the database by matching them to the opportunities in the Projects
    'worksheet. It then assigns row numbers in the Projects worksheet.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Set foundRng = Sheets("Database").Range("C:C").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I end up getting an **Application defined or object defined** error on the `LastRow = Sheets("Projects")...` line.
This is particularly odd as the code never used to give me any sort of error in the past.

Can I please get some help?
Records is the table being targeted.
Database is a table on another sheet where the macro finds what row the record is located on.
Also, should I be using `Worksheet_TableUpdate` instead of `Worksheet_Change`?
See pictures for example:

Records table example [image]

Database table example [image]

Comment: What are you trying to find?  "everything"?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes, just in case someone deleted something from the database, I would want the users to know immediately that their records no longer existed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but do you just want to get the row number of the last populated row in a certain column?  Also, if deletions are the problem, perhaps you would be better to [proactively] prevent them instead of [reactively] report on them?

Comment: @ashleedawg Deletions aren't really a problem. It's just in the last version of my tool, the user didn't know if their record had been created. I hide the database from users so no one is tempted to go meddle in it. So their only feedback would be a row number appearing next to their record.

Comment: An alternative way to get the row number of the last row in a specific column that has data would be something like `Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`  (using Column `C` as an example).  If you want to check if a matching record exists on another worksheet, I'd suggest either the `VLookup` or `Match` functions.

Comment: @ashleedawg That might not work in this case as my data is arranged in columns in the database. The row number is not the last row of the specified column. It is the first row of the data set in the database table.

Comment: Side note: it's a little unclear exactly what you're doing since I think you're mixing up terminology between Access and Excel (unless you're using both).  Access is generally referred to being a Database (of Tables), and an Excel workbook has one or more worksheet, with data stores in ranges of cells.  Just to confuse matters, a range of cells in Excel *can* be setup as a structured table in Excel (usually identified by Excel automatically coloring every 2nd row in different shades), created by (one way) highlighting a range of cells and hitting CTRL+T..

Comment: We are strictly talking about Excel here right?  (By *dictionary defiinition* anything that stores data is technically a "database" but let's avoid that word unless you mean database software.)  is your "database" another ***worksheet*** in the same Excel *workbook*?

Comment: @ashleedawg I am working in Excel only. My table just happens to be called Database. Sorry for the confusion. The Database table feeds a pivot table and needs to be arranged in a certain way. All of this is contained in one workbook and are on the two tables are on separate worksheets.

Comment: anyhow if your concern is the data being in columns versus rows, thhat's the the difference with `VLookup` versus `HLookup`, although in either case `Match` would work, and is probably most versatile.  Regardless, I'm speculating at what you have, it's hard to say what would work without seeing.

Comment: Ah, "user worksheet" and "data worksheet" then.  :-)  Believe me, I understand the importance of keeps your data table organized - and therefore the importance if keeping user's dirty fingers out of it.  :-)  I assume you're actually **hiding ** the worksheet?  Another alternative is to use a completely separate file as a data file (setup with a couple clicks) then there's no risk of data loss (except for the deletions you're allowing).  Depending on your situation, you could also disallow deletions but allow the users to "mark as deleted" so they just "look" like they're deleted to the user

Comment: Anyhow I suppose this has veered off the topic of running specific code when a new row is added to a table.  Did you figure that out?  **If not,** can you clarify whether this is a an Excel **table** or a range of cells?  ((ie, what is the value of `Records`)?

Comment: @ashleedawg I have added two pictures to the original post so you can see what I have been doing. And you are correct, I hide the worksheet containing the `database` table. These are both excel tables, not named ranges or anything like that. User's only input is on the worksheet containing the `records` table. `Database` automatically populates with other macros I created.

Answer (score 1):

The line looks OK to me it must be that this is being applied on a workbook with no Sheet named "Projects"

I would declare the workbook that you are using and triple check that in that workbook there is a sheet named "Projects" (no spaces or a missing s or something like that)

```
Dim wrkbook as workbook
    set wrkbook = Workbooks("WORKBOOKNAME")
    LastRow = Wrkbook.Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```